# condition equal string

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, linqdatasource

```
 <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource2" runat="server" ContextTypeName="DataClassesDataContext"
                       TableName="PrivateMessages" Where="Sender == @Sender">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Sender"  QueryStringField="idCompany" Type="String" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>:LinqDataSource>
```

this code select from table `PrivateMessages` where `Sender==QueryString('idCompany')`
this code work fine.

i want select from `privateMessage` where `Sender=="admin"`????????

where sender equal a const string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Selecting` event and do like..

```
protected void LinqDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
    e.WhereParameters["Sender"] = set here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can replace the `WhereParameters` section with something like

```
 <WhereParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Sender" Type="String" DefaultValue="admin" />
 </WhereParameters>
```

Depends on you in choosing what flavor of this 2 solutions best suits this scenario.